# Can't copy between screens anymore using tmux 2.6 on OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Tags: vim, tmux

I guess I screwed up by upgrading because my tmux has become a mess. I can no longer copy between screens using VIM bindings (yy/p / Shift-V / etc...). Basically typing yy in screen 1, switching to screen 2, then typing p only pastes screen 2's clipboard. I've tried about a dozen solutions scattered across the internet but many seem to require Sierra. I can't upgrade at the moment. I'm out of town and can only upgrade once I'm back on my company's network which won't be for a few more days. Here is my current tmux configuration file. I appreciate any advice.

OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
tmux 2.6 (homebrew)
iterm2 (3.1.2) (homebrew)
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Sep 28 2017 21:29:15) (homebrew)

```
set-option -g default-shell $SHELL
set-option -g allow-rename off

#set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
#set -g default-terminal "tmux"
#set -as terminal-overrides ',xterm*:sitm=\E[3m' # this probably only needs to happen in OS X]'
#

set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /bin/zsh"

set -s escape-time 1

set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

# Mouse support ------------------------------------------------
set-option -g mouse on

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi WheelUpPane send -X scroll-up
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi WheelDownPane send -X scroll-down

# Vi copypaste
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy" \; display-message "highlighted selection copied to system clipboard"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection


# # End Mouse support --------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarassing. I had a symbolic link mishap and had reverted to using OSX's default vim version 7.x. Once I restored my symlink to Homebrew's vim 8 everything starting working.